disable all elements of mui react-number-input
I am using customized number-input from this MUI link.
I want to disable all of its elements conditionally (i.e. 2 buttons and an input).
I tried to adding 'disabled' attribute on main-input component but it only disabled the input and not buttons. same code from the given link has been used.
Please help!
